# Move to Next Column Again over Again

Tags: excel, vba

I have wrote a code to move to next Column over running the code but its not working whereas no error is occur.

I want that it should move to next Column again over again when code is run and repeat this.

For example: I run the code 1st time it will move to BD4 upon 2nd time it will move to BE4 then BF4 then BG4 then BH4 then BI4 and so on.

If is used this line `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select` and select BC4 it will move over running the code. Trying to make a same code but it will start from BC4.

I will really appreciate your help.

```
Sub Move()
With Sheet7.Range("BC4")
.Offset(0, 1).Activate
End With
End Sub
```

Wrote this as well but no success.

```
Sub Move()
Sheet7.Range("BC4").Select
With Selection
.Offset(0, 1).Activate
End With
End Sub
```

Wrote this as well but no success.

```
Sub Move()
Dim FirstCell As String
Dim i As Integer
FirstCell = "BC4"
Range(FirstCell).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The code does nothing, it just activates `BD4`, what do you expect it to do?  As far as I can see it does what it is told to do.

Comment: I want that it should move to next Column again when code is run and repeat this.

Comment: then change `With Sheet7.Range("BC4")` to `With Selection`

Comment: With Selection
Sheet7.Range("BC4").Offset(0, 1).Activate Like this.

Comment: no, replace the line with what I gave you.

Comment: Actually i want to start this from "BC4" and move ahead. With selection it will work by selected cell from the sheet.

Comment: I think this is a XY problem.  We need more details into the whole of what you are trying to do.  Obviously, moving one cell to the right is not the end of this, otherwise one would just hit the right arrow key.  So to help we need to know more details not just what you want here.  It is a little too specific.

Comment: Updated: For example: I run the code 1st time it will move to BD4 upon 2nd time it will move to BE4 then BF4 then BG4 then BH4 then BI4 and so on.

Comment: are you going to manually interact with the active cell then run it again or are you going to do something in the code then want to loop to the next cell.

Comment: Yes will need a loop to go to the next cell instead of selecting cell.

Comment: That did not answer my question, so one last time.  Are you going to interact with the cell manually then run the code to move to the next cell, or are you going to start in BC4 do something with vba then move to the next and do something and loop until some nebulaous instance to stop?

Comment: Yes i will try to create a loop to start it with BC4 thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: The gif helped**

There are really two conditions to consider here: (1) the activecell is outside of the navigation range, (2) the active cell is already within the navigation range.

In my opinion, your best bet is to define the cells across which you want to navigate. If the macro is called when outside this range, jump to the first cell in the range. Otherwise, move to the right. See the below sample code, and let me know if it works for you:

```
Sub Move()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim navigationRange As Range
    
    Set sht = Sheet7
    sht.Select
    
    'This is the range over which you want to navigate
    Set navigationRange = sht.Range("BC4:DD4")
    
    'If you're not already within the navigation range
    'then go to the first cell of the navigation range
    If Intersect(ActiveCell, navigationRange) Is Nothing Then
        navigationRange.Range("a1").Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(, 1).Select
End Sub
```

---

Old post

Here's a simple example of looping to the left 10 times. You can update the code to do whatever you need during each iterations.

```
Sub Move()
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Sheet7.Range("BC4")
    Sheet7.Select
    
    'Mock loop with 10 iterations
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
        rng.Select
        'Do whatever you wanted to do here
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I got your point i added this line after offset rng.Activate but still its not moving to next Column. @basodre

Comment: @Mento You can use `rng.Select` (make sure that the sheet is activated first). Generally, however, you don't need to select the cell before you work with it. It's considered a best practice not to select the cell.

Comment: Then how to move to next cell it still not working even after change to rng,select. It still not move but if i use thins single line then my code works ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

Comment: @Mento See the update. first, I made sure to select the relevant sheet (since the sheet must be active for the cell to be selected. Then, after setting the `rng` variable, i select the range. You can step through the code to see it happening.

Comment: I think i am unable to elaborate my question let me share once again. I just want that if i press the button code will select BD4 again press the button code will select BE4. i want to go on next cell one by one.

Comment: I have added a gif might it could help what i have been trying to do. @basodre

Comment: @Mento The gif clarified your expectations. Please see my edited post/code and let me know if you can get this to work.